# Sumar columnas Java con SQL y mostrarlo en un JTable

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Hola gente tengo una duda, es la siguiente, quiero sumar dos columnas de un `JTable` y arrojar el resultado a un textField, dejare una imagen para que se entienda a que me refiero
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la cual quiero que se multiplique `precio*cantidad` y me arroje el resultado en dicho textfield. Dejo mi codigo de SQL, ya que solo hago un arreglo y invoco los atributos de la BD.

```
try {
        jtMenu.setModel(modelo);
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Conexion conn = new Conexion();
        java.sql.Connection con = conn.getConexion();

        String sql = "SELECT idproducto,idmenu,nombremenu,nombreproducto,descripcion,precio,cantidad FROM menus";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        ResultSetMetaData rsMd = (ResultSetMetaData) rs.getMetaData();
        int cantidadColumnas = rsMd.getColumnCount();

        modelo.addColumn("idproducto");
        modelo.addColumn("idmenu");
        modelo.addColumn("nombremenu");
        modelo.addColumn("nombreproducto");
        modelo.addColumn("descripcion");
        modelo.addColumn("precio");
        modelo.addColumn("cantidad");

        int[] anchos = {50, 200, 50, 50,50,50,50};
        for (int i = 0; i < jtMenu.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            jtMenu.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(anchos[i]);
        }

        while (rs.next()) {
            Object[] filas = new Object[cantidadColumnas];
            for (int i = 0; i < cantidadColumnas; i++) {
                filas[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
            }
            modelo.addRow(filas);
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.toString());
    }

}
```

Saludos! espero respuestas, aclaro que estoy trabajando con sql workbeanch o que solucion me pueden dar , gracias

Comment: Lo primero que necesitas para hacer un programa es saber qué quieres. Describes en tu pregunta dos cosas distintas, aunque ambas se llamen "tabla": Una tabla en la interface de usuario y una tabla en la base de datos. ¿A partir de cuál quieres calcular los totales? Si es a partir de la tabla interface, la parte de SQL no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta.  Si es a partir de la tabla de BD, el hecho de que por otra parte muestres una tabla de interface no importa para nada. Si no sabes qué quieres hacer, no podemos ayudarte a hacerlo.

Comment: Revisa si esto te sirve: `String sql = "SELECT idproducto,idmenu,nombremenu,nombreproducto,descripcion,precio,cantidad, cantidad * precio as Total FROM menus";` Sólo te faltaría agregar el Total al textbox. Saludos!